# postgresql pset title with internal variable value

Tags: postgresql, psql

What is the syntax for setting a report title with spaces and `:value` ? I can set and use the value of an internal variable like this:

```
=> \set TBLNAME host_code_dim

=> select * from monitor.:TBLNAME ;
```

Since that works, I am attempting to resolve `:TBLNAME` in a report title:

```
=> \pset title "From :TBLNAME"
```

That gives `"From :TBLNAME"`

```
=> \pset title 'From :TBLNAME'
```

That gives `From :TBLNAME`

```
=> \pset title From :TBLNAME

Title is "From".
\pset: extra argument ":TBLNAME" ignored
```

Replacing ' ' with '_' works but is not ideal :

```
=> \pset title From_:TBLNAME
Title is "From_host_code_dim".
```

Gives `From_host_code_dim`.

How to get spaces and other punctuation into the title with the value of the internal variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\pset title 'From ':TBLNAME
```

Comment: Thanks. Obvious now. And I thought I had tried that ......